JOIN, where all rows are subset of another table
I want to join over 10 tables, then get id column from a specific table.
The scenario is a little complicated, but let's simplify it here.
Let's say we have three tables, posts, users and tags. Like thsese:
+-------------------+
| posts             |
+----------+--------+
| posts_id | title  |
+----------+--------+
| 1        | post_1 |
| 2        | post_2 |
+----------+--------+

+------------------+
| users            |
+----------+-------+
| users_id | email |
+----------+-------+
| 1        | a@b.c |
| 2        | x@y.z |
+----------+-------+

+-----------------+
| tags            |
+---------+-------+
| tags_id | label |
+---------+-------+
| 1       | tag_1 |
| 2       | tag_2 |
| 3       | tag_3 |
| 4       | tag_4 |
+---------+-------+

Each posts has many tags:
+------------------------+
| posts_tags             |
+----+---------+---------+
| id | post_id | tags_id |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | 1       | 1       |
| 2  | 1       | 2       |
| 3  | 1       | 3       |
| 4  | 2       | 2       |
| 5  | 2       | 3       |
+----+---------+---------+

Also, each users is subscribed to many tags too:
+------------------------+
| users_tags             |
+----+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | tags_id |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | 1       | 1       |
| 2  | 1       | 2       |
| 4  | 2       | 2       |
| 5  | 2       | 3       |
| 6  | 2       | 4       |
+----+---------+---------+

I want to find all posts that all of their tags, are subscribed by a user.
In example above, post_2 has 2 tags: tag_2 and tag_3.
Also, user_2 has subscribed to 3 tags: tag_2, tag_3, and tag_4
All posts_2 tags are subset of user_2 tags, so I want to select posts_2's posts_id column
But posts_ has a tag that the user_2 is not subscribed to (tag_1), so I don't want to select this row.
Here is a sample code I wrote, but is incomplete:
SELECT `posts_id` FROM `posts`
INNER JOIN `posts_tags` USING (`posts_id`)
INNER JOIN `users_tags` USING (`tag_id`)
***** SOME MAGIC HERE *****
WHERE `users_tags`.`user_id` = 2

The SQL code should work on both sqlite and mysql/mariadb.

which database ? is this sql, mysql, sqllite, or mariadb?  I

If its Mysql, take a look over here so you can get a little understanding on how Joins work.  There are 4 types of joins depending on what you want returning, and you can use the ON command to specify the key that links each table together if needed.  See this link for info : https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join.asp

This type of query is called "relational division," and there have been examples posted on Stack Overflow many times. Check some of them out by following the tag I added.

@easleyfixed: w3schools is generally considered a bad resource for learning SQL. Their description of the join types is rather horrible, and the Venn diagrams they are using are quite inappropriate for properly explaining joins, too.

Some people say that, but I have had no issues learning from it on that subject.  I think that is a subjective opinion from those that never used it, or learned a different language on there and assume all the teachings are identical.

@easleyfixed, there's a reason people who really know SQL call it w3f**ls.

Do I understand your request correctly: You want to show all posts for which at least one user subscribed to all its tags?
In that case cross join posts_tags with users, so as to get all data sets (groups of post + user) that may be a match. I put separator lines between the groups, so you can see them better:
+----+---------+---------+----------+-------+
| id | post_id | tags_id | users_id | email |
+----+---------+---------+----------+-------+
| 1  | 1       | 1       | 1        | a@b.c |
| 2  | 1       | 2       | 1        | a@b.c |
| 3  | 1       | 3       | 1        | a@b.c |
+----+---------+---------+----------+-------+
| 1  | 1       | 1       | 2        | x@y.z |
| 2  | 1       | 2       | 2        | x@y.z |
| 3  | 1       | 3       | 2        | x@y.z |
+----+---------+---------+----------+-------+
| 4  | 2       | 2       | 1        | a@b.c |
| 5  | 2       | 3       | 1        | a@b.c |
+----+---------+---------+----------+-------+
| 4  | 2       | 2       | 2        | x@y.z |
| 5  | 2       | 3       | 2        | x@y.z |
+----+---------+---------+----------+-------+

Then outer join the users_tags:
+----+---------+---------+----------+-------+----+---------+---------+
| id | post_id | tags_id | users_id | email | id | user_id | tags_id |
+----+---------+---------+----------+-------+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | 1       | 1       | 1        | a@b.c | 1  | 1       | 1       |
| 2  | 1       | 2       | 1        | a@b.c | 2  | 1       | 2       |
| 3  | 1       | 3       | 1        | a@b.c |    |         |         |
+----+---------+---------+----------+-------+----|---------+---------+
| 1  | 1       | 1       | 2        | x@y.z |    |         |         |
| 2  | 1       | 2       | 2        | x@y.z | 4  | 2       | 2       |
| 3  | 1       | 3       | 2        | x@y.z | 5  | 2       | 3       |
+----+---------+---------+----------+-------+----+---------+---------+
| 4  | 2       | 2       | 1        | a@b.c | 1  | 1       | 2       |
| 5  | 2       | 3       | 1        | a@b.c |    |         |         |
+----+---------+---------+----------+-------+----|---------+---------+
| 4  | 2       | 2       | 2        | x@y.z | 4  | 2       | 2       |
| 5  | 2       | 3       | 2        | x@y.z | 5  | 2       | 3       |
+----+---------+---------+----------+-------+----+---------+---------+

If you now look at the post/user groups, you see that we have only one match: For post 2 / user 2 there is no user tag missing. Thus we find post 2. Depending on the data there could also be more than one user matching a post's tags, so we must add DISTINCT in order not to select the same post multiple times.
The query:
select distinct pt.posts_id
from posts_tags pt
cross join users u
left join users_tags ut on ut.tags_id = pt.tags_id and ut.user_id = u.user_id
group by pt.posts_id, u.user_id
having count(*) = count(ut.id)
order by pt.posts_id;

If you just want to check for one user, e.g. user 2, then the query becomes a tad simpler, because we don't have to join users anymore and we cannot get duplicates:
select pt.posts_id
from posts_tags pt
left join users_tags ut on ut.tags_id = pt.tags_id and ut.user_id = 2
group by pt.posts_id
having count(*) = count(ut.id)
order by pt.posts_id;


Going by the description in your post, I think you're still on track. You only need to inner join still on the users table. And if you wish to get information from the tags table as well, you might want to also join on the tags table as shown below to get all the posts that their tags are subscribed by the users.
SELECT posts.id, tags.id, users.id
FROM posts
INNER JOIN posts_tags ON posts_tags.post_id = posts.id
INNER JOIN users_tags ON users_tags.tags_id = posts_tags.tags_id
INNER JOIN tags ON users_tags.tags_id = tags.id
INNER users ON users_tags.user_id = users.id

To query the tables for a certain user, let say user 2, you would ideally add a where clause in the query above such as
WHERE users.id = 2


they only want posts where all of the posts tags are subscribed to by the user
